# Is a later release of .NET Core 3.1.x backwards compatible across the same major and minor releases?

Tags: .net-core, version, visual-studio-mac

.NET Core 3.1.301 and 5.0.100 SDKs are installed on my machine. When I try build a nopCommerce solution, I get the following build error:

```
Error: .NET Core 3.1.201 SDK is required to build this application, and is not installed. Install the latest update to the .NET Core 3.1.201 SDK by visiting https://aka.ms/vs/mac/install-netcore31 (Nop.Core)
```

I was under the assumption that .NET Core is backwards compatible across major and minor releases. If my assumption is correct, is it possible to tie down a build to a specific version of .NET Core? If so, where is it set and why would it be desirable to do so?

Comment: Edit `global.json` file to remove that SDK version restriction and you should then be fine to compile it. It is simply the intention of the original developers to stick to a certain version for their ease of use, but you might not like that very much.